# Migrate Trac to Redmine on Different Server

Tags: migration, trac, redmine

I have two servers - one with trac and one with a new Redmine installation.  The trac server has a lot of valuable information on it (wiki pages, etc) that I would like to get to the Redmine server.  I have found [this migration script](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineMigrate) online, but it's under the assumption that both services are on the same server.  I'm attempting to transfer this information across two different servers.

I will say it is possible for both servers to see each other over the network, but cross-network migration doesn't sound like an easy task to figure out.

Are there any suggestions?